# material 2 RTL dialog not center

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I  change the angular material 2 dialog  example 
https://stackblitz.com/angular/bydbkvrmyeb?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts
to RTL by adding `direction: 'rtl',`

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      direction: 'rtl',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
    });
```

the popup is NOT in the center of the page any more

Answer (score 0):

The direction tag is for the layout. That means the modal would be laid in that fashion. Please check the below link and search for the `direction` tag.

> https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

However, if you wish to have the direction in your HTML, you may apply CSS and put the desired direction like below:-

**dialog-overview-example-dialog.html**

```
<div style="direction: rtl;">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
  <div mat-dialog-content>
    <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may check the running example for your reference.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syrsnb?file=app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.html

Comment: the issue with this solution is that the direction of the input field is LTR and not RTL see here http://prntscr.com/k37dxv

Comment: You may apply a class with direction:rtl to the input tag and write a JS on keyUp to append the key pressed to the beginning of the string.

Comment: I am looking for a robust solution, applying RTL to the dialog and maintaining its features ....

Comment: You cannot apply RTL just to the modal and get the input working.

Comment: meaning material dialog does not support RTL ?  in the sense the dialog is not center in RTL ?

Comment: Your problem is related to the modal not in the center, and that has been solved. If you are considering to get the contents of the modal to follow certain direction, you need to explicitly set it. Material design does not provide that out of the box for the modal as the `direction` property is related to the layout of the modal itself.

Comment: For Android phone dialog is not cmg in center. :(

Comment: @siddharthashankar - I thought the answer did not help.